# Does the client need an azure account in order to request azure storage resource?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am new to Azure. I am writing my first REST API to update an Azure storage blob.

As part of the REST API header, I need to provide an authorization header as follows:

Authorization="[SharedKey|SharedKeyLite] [AccountName]:Signature"

Noticing the [AccountName] part: Does it mean that the client (issuing the API request) also needs to have an Azure account in order to request the storage resource?

Thanks in advance.
Mikey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find `AccountName` by going to azure portal -> your azure storage account:

[image]

Yes, the client of course needs the `AccountName` in the `Authorization` header.

The doc [Specifying the Authorization header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#specifying-the-authorization-header) describes it clear. And we have done many works via blob storage api(like create, delete etc.), without `AccountName` in `Authorization` header, it fails to authentication.

Please let me know if you still have more issues.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What can be used as <AccountName>? Azure login email address?

Comment: it's your azure storage account name.

Comment: In my case, the client (who needs to request write access from the storage) does not have a storage account,. Instead, the client is really a python server that needs to update the requested storage.

Comment: @MIkey, if the server does not know the storage account, how does it do any operation to these files which are stored in storage account? That's impossible.

Comment: @MIkey, for example, if the server uses the [put-blob api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob), then the server needs a `url to the file`, right? you can find the `account name` in the url. For example, in [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob#request), the request url is `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob`, then you can find the `account name` is `myaccount`.

Comment: So the account name is really the storage account that provides the blob?  According to Microsoft, accountname is the nam eof the aaoccunt "REQUESTING" the resoucre? Here is an exact copy of Microsoft's document: where SharedKey or SharedKeyLite is the name of the authorization scheme, AccountName is the name of the account requesting the resource, and Signature is a Hash-based Message Authentication Code (HMAC) constructed from the request and computed by using the SHA256 algorithm, and then encoded by using Base64 encoding.

Comment: @MIkey, of course, we have done many works via blob storage api. I'm 100% sure. And another easy way to use these api is by using sas_token, it's much easier to build a sas_token than shared key.

Comment: So what Microsoft is saying that both ends of the transaction (requesting end and requested end) all need to have at least one storage account, despite that the client-side (the one who is making the request) may not need a storage account at all?

Comment: @MIkey, no, if you send a request from anywhere, you need the account name to build the Authorization token.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps Microsoft should re-phrase it as:  account name is the name of the account that provides the storage resource.

Comment: @MIkey, you're welcome. If the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? And if you encounter any issues, please @ me.

Comment: @MIkey, ok:). so could you please accept it as answer, as per [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)? Thanks:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227015/discussion-between-mikey-and-ivan-yang).